# Are MSO formulae expressible as existential SO formulae over arbitrary structures?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Given an MSO formulae φ, which may contain arbitrary quantifier alternation, is there always an ESO formula ψ, such that φ and ψ have the same (finite) models?

(This statement holds when the models we are interested in are restricted to words and trees, as one can translate φ to an automaton and back to an MSO formula with an existential quantifier prefix. So the question is really about the general case.)

Answer (score 7):

In MSO one can say that a graph is *not* $3$-colorable:
$$\forall C_1 \forall C_2 \forall C_3 (``\text{$C_1,C_2,C_3$ are disjoint sets that cover the graph''} \to \exists x \exists y (E(x,y) \land \bigvee_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} (C_i(x) \land C_i(y)))$$
Since over finite structures ESO is contained in $NP$ and non $3$-colorability is $coNP$-hard, over finite structures non $3$-colorability is not definable in ESO unless $NP = coNP$. So, probably MSO is not contained in ESO over finite structures.

MSO is also not contained in ESO over general structures. For instance, in MSO one can axiomatize the standard structure of real numbers up to isomorphism (which is an uncountable structure) while every ESO sentence that has an infinite model has a countably infinite model (due to the fact that ESO has the countable downwards Löwenheim-Skolem property).

Comment: Thanks! The second argument separates MSO and ESO for infinite structures. It would still be nice to find an argument for finite structures that does not rely on NP ≠ coNP.

Comment: @FlorianZuleger I think that MSO $\subseteq$ ESO in the finite is equivalent with NP = coNP. Indeed, if NP = coNP, then PH collapses to NP; in particular, it would follow that in the finite the whole SO is contained in ESO. My answer shows that MSO $\subseteq$ ESO implies in turn that NP = coNP.

Answer (score 4):

An SO formula quantifying over $k$-ary relations can be expressed as an MSO formula over a larger structure that includes the $k$th cartesian power of the original structure. Thus, up to a polynomial-time blow-up, MSO over arbitrary finite structures can express the whole polynomial hierarchy. (See e.g. Prop. 7.35 in Libkin, [Elements of Finite Model Theory](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf), for another argument.)

Comment: As the approach you suggest requires changing the structure it does not help my question where I am interested in finding an ESO formula ψ that has the same models as a given MSO formula φ.

Comment: It tells you that the answer to the question is negative (assuming NP $\ne$ coNP), because it would imply that every PH language is polynomial-time reducible to an ESO language, and therefore is in NP.